# Difference between `sales_order_place_after` and `sales_order_save_after`?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, orders, event-observer

Magento 1 and Magento 2 both have the two event:

1. `sales_order_place_after`
2. `sales_order_save_after`.

I have some confusion about them, what is the **detailed differences** between them?

Which situation to use which?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**sales_order_place_after**

1. This event is dispatched after the order payment is placed.
2. This event function from `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::place()` in Magento 1 & `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::place()` in Magento 2

**sales_order_save_after**

1. This event is called every time the order is saved. For eg. Order status changed, invoiced, shipped & credit memo.
2. This event extending the abstract model `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`

   For eg. the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class event prefix is `sales_order`, so the actual after loading event’s name will be `sales_order_load_after`.

Answer (score 6):

**1. sales_order_place_after:**

This event is dispatched from the

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract
{
...
public function place()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_place_before', array('order'=>$this));
    $this->_placePayment();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_place_after', array('order'=>$this));
    return $this;
}
```

This event is dispatched only after clicking place order from frontend.

**2. sales_order_save_after:**

This event is triggered on **saving order, either from backend or frontend.** Everytime some edit is made in order and saved, this event is dispatched. This event is dispatched while placing order from frontend as well.